# Pop array element based on object property and value

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how can I extract a single object from an array by an object property and value,
Something in the line of:

```
let arr = [{temp:36, night: false}, {temp:12, night: true}, {temp:24, night: true}]
let Obj = arr.pop({night:true})
// obj: {temp:12, night: true}
// arr now: [{temp:36, night: false}, {temp:24, night: true}]
```

Any advice?

Comment: remove the first element where night:true ?

Comment: Are you okay with using a for loop every time you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your own function, iterate your target array, and splice to a new array

```
function removeElements(arr, prop, value) {
    let poppedElems = [];
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) && arr[i][prop] === value) {
            poppedElems = poppedElems.concat(arr.splice(i, 1));
        }
    }

    return poppedElems
}
```

If you just want the first one:

```
function findElement(arr, prop, value) {
    let elem = null;
    let elemIndex = arr.findIndex(x => x.hasOwnProperty(prop) && x[prop] === value);

    if (elemIndex !== -1) {
        elem = arr.splice(elemIndex, 1)[0];
    }         

    return elem;
}
```

Comment: He only wants the first one.

Comment: @Helium_1s2 - Added method to do just 1.

Comment: works pretty nice :) will select if no nicer answer will rise up

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a loop
2. Check for property value
3. Remove it form array with `splice` and break the loop

```js
let arr = [{temp:36, night: false}, {temp:12, night: true}, {temp:24, night: true}],
    test = {night:true};
    required = null;
    


function doTheStuff(obj, arr){
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

    if(arr[i].night == test.night){
         required = arr[i]
         arr.splice(i,1);
         break;
    }
}
}

  doTheStuff(test,arr)
console.log("required" , required)
console.log("arr", arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following Array:

```
let arr = [{temp:36, night: false}, {temp:12, night: true}, {temp:24, night: true}];
```

The easiest way would be using the **findIndex()** method.

Returns the first element where night is false:

```
let index = arr.findIndex(elem => !elem.night);
// index = 0
```

Returns the first element where night is true:

```
let index = arr.findIndex(elem => elem.night)
// index = 1
```

Then to get the element:

```
let obj = arr[index];
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll probably want to use `findIndex`, which finds the index of the first element that satisfies the provided testing function. `find` would also work, but then you don't know where it is in the array, so you can't delete it if you need to. `bind` allows you to pass parameters into `findMatch`, so you can select your property and search value without having to write more functions.

A working example would be

```
arr = [{temp:36, night: false}, {temp:12, night: true}, {temp:24, night: true}];
config = {
    propName: "night",
    propVal: true
};
function findMatch(elt) {
    return elt[this.propName] == this.propVal;
}
ind = arr.findIndex(findMatch.bind(config));
elt = arr[ind];
arr.splice(ind, 1); //Delete 1 element at position ind
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, I am looking for something dynamic, so I could pass which ever prop & value as I want in order to pop the element. Something as: arr.findIndex(func, prop, value)

Comment: @Captain_Meow_Meow this will work for any property and expected value.

Answer (score -1):

You `find` method to get the first one with `night: false`

```
let arr = [{temp:36, night: false}, {temp:12, night: true}, {temp:24, night: true}]
arr = arr.find(a => !a.night)
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

Comment: He only wants the first value, not all of them.

Comment: @Helium_1s2 Ah, my bad.. Now I edited the answer. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score -1):

Misunderstood the question initially. Revised answer is as succinct as possible:

```
var arr = [{temp:36, night: false}, {temp:12, night: true}, {temp:24, night: true}];
let obj;

var key = 'night';
var value = true;


for(var item in arr){
  if(arr[item][key]==value){
    obj = arr[item];
    arr.splice(item,1);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: He only wants the first one. His example is quite clear about that.

Comment: The `forEach` will only cut the first one. Try it! https://jsbin.com/woyuxiduqu/edit?js,console

Comment: Your first solution cuts out the second and third elements of the array, only leaving behind the first element.

Comment: Nope. Check the jsbin.

Comment: That's the second solution you posted. I said the first one doesn't work. Which it doesn't. https://jsbin.com/gokujex/edit?js,console Notice how it deletes both elements.

Comment: And you second solution doesn't work if the array is longer than 3. https://jsbin.com/rosokig/edit?js,console